# How can I run func2 while running func1 in GUI?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, pyqt5

First, sorry for my English.

Hi, I'm trying to make interface of motor control with Python PyQt5(Qt designer).

If I run one function with clicked button, the GUI window has no response. Therefore, I can't push any other button.

I found the solution is maybe connected with `QThread` or `DemonThread`, but I didn't made it.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import time


form_class = uic.loadUiType("Test_GUI3.ui")[0]

# class Thread1(QThread):
#     def __init__(self, parent):
#         super().__init__(parent)
#     def RUN(self):
#         print("you made it!")

class MyWindow(QMainWindow, form_class):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.test.clicked.connect(self.TEST)
    self.test_2.clicked.connect(self.TEST_2)

def TEST(self):
    while True:
        print("cheer up")
        time.sleep(1)

def TEST_2(self):
    print("you made it!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    myWindow = MyWindow()
    myWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfxEs.png)

If I click "test" button, the while loop is run. But GUI("MainWindow") has no response.

I want to make it like this.

1. Click "test" button.
2. Click "test_2" button and stop "TEST" function and run "TEST_2" function.

Thank you for read it.

Comment: Your `TEST` and `TEST_2` functions need to share information.  `TEST_2` should set a piece of state that `TEST` checks to know that it should stop.  You should *also* be doing your `TEST` sleep on another thread so it's not blocking the UI.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, hey Uidos, no offence taking by your english, you speak quite well actually. Now, down to business...

You need to create an if statement in each function:

```
func1 = func2 = False

def TEST(self):
    func1 = True
    func2 = False
    if func1 == True:
            print("cheer up")
            time.sleep(1)
def TEST_2(self):
    func1 = False
    func2 = True
    if func2 == True:
        print("you made it!")
```

Now let me explain... What this code does is that when one button is clicked, it changes the status of that function to true and changes the other to false... The if statements basically mean that the function will NOT execute if it's false, hereby creating a way to kill a function once another is called. Your while statement did not work the way you wanted it to because you never provided a way to make the function false, so when you clicked the button the function is always true. Additionally, `while True` was not the correct term to use, because that checks if a variable called "True" is true. So basically, you were even just telling python to check whether an undefined variable is true, and it's obviously false. You had the right idea though, as you can replace my if statements with while loops instead, that would be much more clean and pythonic.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot. However, my problem was "GUI("MainWindow") has no response" while function is running. In order to solve safety problem of motor, I have to make Motor off button while motor function is running in GUI. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Oh your welcome... I'm sorry I didn't pay enough attention to the question